# gson deserialize list of list elements

Tags: java

I'm trying to deserialize a list of list containing person object but get an error.

```
            gson = new Gson();
            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<List<Person>>>(){}.getType(); 
            List<List<Person>> persons = gson.fromJson("[['1','Mark'],['2','Dave']]", listType); 
            System.out.println("persons:" +persons);
```

Error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 4 path $[0][0]
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
```

Person.java

```
class Person{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    Person(){

    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your JSON doesn't correspond at all to your data structure. `List<List<Person>>` would look like this: `[[{"id": "1", "name": "mark"}, {"id": "2", "name": "dave"}]]`

Comment: Thanks,The api that I’m calling reruns just a list of list as mentioned, should I write my custom serializer?

Comment: I think you should write a little code to transit List<List<String>> to List<Person> @user1050619